Missing package error when trying to import cross modules entities
I am working on this Spring Boot Microservices project. I am trying to use an entity from another module. The import statements all looks good. But when I do mvn clean install on one of the module, that requires the other module, I get an error something like:

"package com.spring.food.user_service.model does not exist"

pom.xml of restaurant_service:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.spring.food.user_service</groupId>
    <artifactId>user_service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

Here is the relevant code
RestaurantController.java:
package com.spring.food.restaurant_service.controller;

import com.spring.food.restaurant_service.dto.CreateRestaurantRequest;
import com.spring.food.restaurant_service.model.Restaurant;
import com.spring.food.restaurant_service.service.RestaurantService;
import com.spring.food.user_service.model.USER_ROLE;
import com.spring.food.user_service.model.User;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/restaurant")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestaurantController {

    private final RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Restaurant> createRestaurant(@RequestBody CreateRestaurantRequest request) {

        User user = new User();
        //user.setUserId(1L);
        user.setFullName("Xavier");
        user.setEmail("xavieer@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("xavier");
        user.setRole(USER_ROLE.ROLE_RESTAURANT_OWNER);

        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantService.createRestaurant(request, user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(restaurant, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

Now when I run one of maven life cycle phase:
mvn clean install

The error:

package com.spring.food.user_service.model does not exist


You cannot use a spring boot application as a dependency due to the structure of the jar file.
